# How to correctly grab matrix from Queue (opencv)

Tags: opencv, c++17

I try to make frame grabber class from IP Camera using std::queue and opencv

In this class, It takes and store maximum 10 frame,

and Other class, get frame from buffer.

```
/* Camera.cpp */
struct FRAME
{
    cv::Mat  Img;
    uint64_t Time;
    bool     ReadError;
};

class Camera
{
    std::queue<FRAME>    m_buffer;
    std::mutex           m_buffer_mutex;
    ...
};

void Camera::threadFunc_get_stream_from_camera()
{
    while (true)
    {
        FRAME frame;

        ... // read sequence (if cv::read is fail, store frame routine is skipping)

        m_buffer_mutex.lock();

        while (m_buffer.size() >= 10)
            m_buffer.pop();

        m_buffer.push(frame);

        m_buffer_mutex.unlock();
    }
}

FRAME Camera::grab()
{
    std::unique_lock ulock(m_buffer_mutex);

    FRAME frame;
    if (m_buffer.empty() == false)
    {
        frame = m_buffer.front();
        m_buffer.pop();
        return frame;
    }
}

/***************/
/* Testing.cpp */

int main()
{
    // Camera* cam ..
    ...

    while (true)
    {
        auto frame = cam->grab();

        if (frame.Img.data == nullptr || frame.Time == 0)
            continue;

        ... // frame image processing
    }
}
```

I kept the program this way for about 3 days, and no special bugs or memory sticks were found.

But the reason I'm asking this question is,

whether it's right to use non-pointer(FRAME) in grab() function.

I'm using C++17, and I think there is no problem because the uint64_t or bool values in the structure are copied in this version.

but, How about cv::Mat ?

I don't want to using Producer-Consumer pattern, because not want to contain testing class side's code in Camera class.

Comment: `cv::Mat` is basically a fancy `shared_ptr` around the underlying data buffer. It does shallow copies by default. Since you create a new `FRAME` instance in each iteration of the `while` loop, this looks fine.

Comment: I thought 3 way for implement. First is pointer variable (FRAME*). but (repeated new, delete) needs some more resource(time, memory etc.) compare with other ways. Second is reference. But when I used this method, In m_buffer, the reference(auto&) is taken through front(), but after pop(), it is lost. Therefore, I had no choice but to choose the normal type. Even if it causes unnecessary copying.

Comment: Yeah, like I said, this is fine. Shallow copies are cheap -- it's just the metadata (sizes, data type) and the pointer that get copied, not the underlying data buffer of the `Mat`. | Anyway, the most memory usage will be the data buffers of the `Mat` objects. Compared to that, the size of `FRAME` is basically irrelevant.

Comment: No problem. It's important to be aware of this behaviour of `Mat` -- if you reused one `Mat` in a loop and inserted shallow copies of it into a queue, you'd find that all of them refer to the same data (the most recent frame).